# Как изменить содержание span на чистом JS

Tags: javascript, html

необходимо поменять содержание span с ">" на "<". Пробовал реализовать с помощью innerHTML и innerText, но не помогло, полагаю для спан нужен другой метод или проблема в другом?

```js
function ReadMore() {
  var more = document.querySelector("#more");
  var display = window.getComputedStyle(more).display;
  var readmore = document.querySelector("#readmore")
  var arrow = document.querySelector("#arrow")
  var mStyle = window.getComputedStyle ? getComputedStyle(more, null) : more.currentStyle;
  if (mStyle.display === "none") {
    more.style.display = "block";
    readmore.innerHTML = "Close"
    arrow.innerText = "<";
  } else {
    more.style.display = "none";
    readmore.innerHTML = "Read More"
    arrow.innerText = ">";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="service_card">
  <div class="service_img">
    <img src="img/servese-1.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="service_text">
    <h4>Express Services</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis aliquid tempora maxime tempore cupiditate, ipsam quidem.<span id="more"> Recusandae voluptates laborum minus et cumque, quam odio aperiam quas dolorem, delectus porro quia?</span></p>
  </div>
  <button id="readmore" onclick="ReadMore()">Read More <span class="arrow">></span> </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Вы попутали селекторы. `#` обозначает поиск по id, а для поиска по классу нужен префикс `.`. У вас `arrow` именно класс
2. Когда вы пишете `readmore.innerHTML =` вы уничтожаете внутренний `span`
3. Изначально у вас текст показан, а на кнопке написано `Read More`

```js
function ReadMore() {
  var more = document.querySelector("#more");
  var display = window.getComputedStyle(more).display;
  var readmore = document.querySelector("#readmore")
  var arrow = document.querySelector(".arrow")
  var mStyle = window.getComputedStyle ? getComputedStyle(more, null) : more.currentStyle;
  if (mStyle.display === "none") {
    more.style.display = "inline";
    readmore.innerHTML = "Close"
    arrow.innerText = "<";
  } else {
    more.style.display = "none";
    readmore.innerHTML = "Read More"
    arrow.innerText = ">";
  }
}
```

```css
#more {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="service_card">
  <div class="service_img">
    <img src="img/servese-1.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="service_text">
    <h4>Express Services</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis aliquid tempora maxime tempore cupiditate, ipsam quidem.<span id="more"> Recusandae voluptates laborum minus et cumque, quam odio aperiam quas dolorem, delectus porro quia?</span></p>
  </div>
  <button onclick="ReadMore()">
    <span id="readmore">Read More</span> <span class="arrow">></span> </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var button = document.querySelector('#readmore');

button.addEventListener('click', changeArrowDirection);

function changeArrowDirection(e) {
  var arrow = document.querySelector('.arrow');
  arrow.innerText == '>' ? arrow.innerText = '<' : arrow.innerText = '>';
}
```

```html
<button id="readmore">Read More <span class="arrow">></span></button>
```

Comment: никогда не видал такого использования тернарного оператора. Оно точно работает?

Comment: какого "такого" ? Обычный тернарный оператор.

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex Ну, как правило его используют чтобы куда-нибудь вернуть значение. В таком виде: `arrow.innerText = ( arrow.innerText == ">" ) ? "<" : ">";` А у вас он похож на обычный if )

Comment: Если подобным образом его лучше не юзать, то дайте знать, потому что я постоянно его использую и так и так даже не задумываясь о том, что это кому то в новинку.

Comment: Например в таком виде у вас происходит дублирование кода. Вы в двух местах присваиваете значение `arrow.innerText`

Answer (score 1):

К слову, CSS:

```js
let toggler = document.querySelectorAll('.toggler');
let jsid = document.querySelectorAll('.js-set-id');

for (let i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
  toggler[i].setAttribute('for', "js-id-" + i);
  jsid[i].id = "js-id-" + i;
} // JS - чтобы не возиться с id / for... можно и вручную, если там пара элементов.
```

```css
.hidden, .js-set-id { display: none; }

.more {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#fff, #ddd, #ccc);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.more:active { background-image: linear-gradient(#ccc, #ddd, #fff); }

.more::before { content: "Read More >"; }

.js-set-id:checked ~ .toggler .more::before { content: "Close <"; }

.js-set-id:checked ~ p .hidden { display: inline; }
```

```html
<div>
  <input class="js-set-id" id="input-id" type="checkbox">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor ame... <span class="hidden">More text bubu, More text bubu, More text bubu, More text bubu, More text bubu, More text bubu, More text bubu, More text bubu, More text bubu, More text bubu, </span></p>
  <label class="toggler" for="input-id"><span class="more"></span></label>
</div>

<hr>

<div>
  <input class="js-set-id" type="checkbox">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor ame... <span class="hidden">More text bubu, More text bubu, More text bubu, More text bubu, More text bubu, More text bubu, More text bubu, </span></p>
  <label class="toggler"><span class="more"></span></label>
</div>
```